# Import multiple 3rd party libraries into same namespace in Angular2 project

Tags: angular, typescript, import, leaflet

I'm making a projet with Angular2. The project is generated with Angular-CLI (1.0.0-beta.17) and uses Angular v2.0.0 with TypeScript.

In this project I would like to import both [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/)(1.0.1) and [Leaflet.VectorGrid](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid)(1.0.2).

I install them with npm

```
npm install leaflet
npm install leaflet.vectorgrid
```

Leaflet has a @types definition, so i installed that as well

```
npm install @types/leaflet
```

Leaflet.VectorGrid however does not have an @types definition, so i add

```
declare module 'leaflet.vectorgrid';
```

to my typings.d.ts file instead.

But how can I then import both modules into the same namespace in my project files ?

If I try :

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import * as L from 'leaflet.vectorgrid';
```

this logically throws a compile error because of the duplicate identifier.
Importing them with different aliases, such as :

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import * as LVG from 'leaflet.vectorgrid';
```

does not work either because Leaflet.VectorGrid extends the global L object so doing

```
LVG.vectorGrid(...)
```

fails.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to import both librairies into the global scope with script tags. Then adding

```
declare var L: any;
```

into any `.ts` file where `L` needs to be used will work. However this is not ideal since L is not really typed and no verifications will be made by the typescript compiler.

To be able to use both libraries with types, one would have to write a type definition for the `Leaflet.VectorGrid` library, which as far as i can tell does not exist right now, and then merge both objects into one.

Answer (score 0):

I think require('path/to/library') will work and you can use it in the typescript.

```
require('node_modules/leaflet/leaflet-xxxxx.js');
```

You can also include Leaflet using require method

```
var L = require('node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js');
```